# How to align same height divs

Tags: css

I've this code

```css
.row {
  width: 600px;
}

.row div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.text {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis incidunt.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want my div `.text` to have the same height as the image.
I want it responsive no I can't set a height to `.text`

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What do you mean "responsive" here? The height of the image will change?

Answer (score 1):

One option is with **Flexbox**

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;;
}

.text {
  background-color: lightblue; 
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis incidunt.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Other one is **CSS table**

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  width: 600px;
  display: table;
}

.text {
  background-color: lightblue; 
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.image {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="image"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis incidunt.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `display-table`:

```css
.row {
  width: 600px;
  display: table;
}

.row > div {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top; /* or 'middle' or 'bottom' etc. */
}

.text {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis incidunt.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution which just uses `height:auto;` :

```css
.row {
width: 600px;
height: auto;
background-color: lightblue;
}

.image, .text {
display: inline-block;
width: 49%;
}

.image {
background-color: white;
}

.text, .image img {
vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis incidunt.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```